# Can Vite mock a module outside of project dependencies?

Tags: jestjs, vitest

I have a JS package that runs in an environment where `require('custompackage')` is injected. I want to make sure that when I run `vitest` that `require('custompackage')` points to my mock.

When I used Jest, I was able to mock this with config like this:

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^custompackage$': '<rootDir>/../../dependency-mocks/custompackage.js',
  },
```

I am struggling to understand the conversion of code like this Vite.

I tried vitest config like this:

```
deps: {
  # i made a custompackage folder and put an index.js file within
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', resolve('./tests/dependency-mocks')],
},
```

The above `deps` I tried both in top level `vitest` config and within the `test` property. I made `./tests/dependency-mocks/custompackage/index.js` along with a `package.json` to further try and spoof the module.

I also tried variations of `alias` and `resolve.alias` that pointed straight at `index.js`. No matter what I tried, I get `Cannot find module 'custompackage'`

Doing `vi.mock('custompackage', () => {})` also seemed to have no effect. I believe it's because vitest would still try to find the real module before mocking, which is why I think that `resolve` is the answer. I just can't seem to crack the right combo.

Another attempt was via `alias` like this:

```
#tried both pointing at folder and specific file
const replacement = resolve(
  __dirname,
  './tests/dependency-mocks/custompackage',
);

....

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      entries: [{ find: 'custompackage', replacement }],
    },
  },
```

One quirk from my environment is that the things I am mocking with no issue are `import X from 'package';` but these special ones are `const x = require('custompackage');`. I thought there possibly an issue with mocking when mixing `import` vs `require`, but I sanity checked it with an `import` instead and I got `Failed to resolve import "custompackage"`

**Update**
I have created a StackBlitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-aqrvdv?file=src%2Fhello.js

You can see my `hello.js` requires a package that is not in my dependency list, so there are no node modules. Despite calling `vi.mock`, it still has an error.

Comment: Could you replicate the problem in a StackBlitz/CodeSandbox app?

Comment: I will start working on that now

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-aqrvdv?file=src%2Fhello.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `commonjs` specifically in a search and found out that `vitest` does not support mocking `require` calls.

https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/discussions/3134

You can install https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require to make tests work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`vi.mock` or `jest.mock` only going to work if you are using that import inside the test file. If your test function is dependent on another function outside that file the mock won't work unless you do it in a global state.

You can use [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array) or [setupFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array)

It can be used as follows:

```json
// Jest config
{
  ...
  setupFiles: ['pathTo/custompackage.js'],
  ...
}
```

Vitest [setup](https://vitest.dev/config/#setupfiles)

```
// vite.config.js
{
  ...

  test: {
    ...
    setup: ['pathTo/custompackage.js']
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

In your setup file, you can mock the import and swap it with whatever you want.

```js
// setup file
vi.mock('custompackage', vi.importActual('mockedCustomPackage'))
```

[importActual](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-importactual)

Comment: I tried that earlier and tried it again for sanity from within my setup file. `vi.mock('custompackage', () => { return {}; });`. I still get `Cannot find module` error